# Pole-Zero Configuration of Glottal Signal

Tags: speech-processing, poles-zeros

I am currently studying for an exam in my Speech Processing course this Friday and I stumbled upon this question in one of the sample exams:

[image: Sample Question]

The answer to this question was given as:

[image: Sample Question Answer]

Can someone explain to me why the pole is drawn in that location and why the reciprocal was taken?

Comment: Recall what a pole is? It's where the z-transform tends to infinity. What value(s) of $z$ would cause $G(z) =\frac{1}{(1-\beta z)^2}\rightarrow \infty$? (This will answer your reciprocal question). Next, note that $\beta <1$. So where would $1/\beta$ go relative to 1? (This will answer your question about why the pole is drawn in the location shown.)

Comment: I converted the comment to an answer if you want to vote/accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall what a pole is? It's where the z-transform tends to infinity. What value(s) of $z$ would cause $G(z) =\frac{1}{(1-\beta z)^2}\rightarrow \infty$? (This will answer your reciprocal question).

Next, note that $\beta <1.$ So where would $\beta$ go relative to 1? 
(This will answer your question about why the pole is drawn in the location shown.)